# NavigationService.Navigate throwing exception when called in Prism for UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, prism, uwp-xaml, prism-6

I am using Prism for UWP and I've base classed my App from PrismUnityApplication. 
I've overridden OnLaunchApplicationAsync and I am trying to call,

```
NavigationService.Navigate("HighlightsView", null);
```

When called, the program throws an exception,

```
{"The page name HighlightsView does not have an associated type in namespace Panda.UWP.Views\r\nParameter name: pageToken"}
```

I do have a folder named Views and I do have a view named HighlightsView under the namespace, Panda.UWP.Views.

Is there a naming convention to be followed here? Because if I rename my view from **HighlightsView** to ***HighlightsPage***, then everything seems to be working just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a naming convention to be followed here?

The short answer is yes.  Prism for the Windows Runtime specifies a `ViewModelLocator` object, that can be used to manage the instantiation of view models and their associations to views. This approach has the advantage that there’s a single class that’s responsible for view model instantiation.

The [`ViewModelLocator`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Mvvm/ViewModelLocator.cs)  class uses an attached property, `AutoWireViewModel`, to associate view models with views once this property is set to True. For more details about the convention please reference [Dave's Tech Blog](http://www.davidbritch.com/2013/06/changing-default-conventions-used-in.html):

- View models are in the same assembly as the view types.
- Views are in a .Views child namespace.
- View names end with “Page”.
- View models are in a .ViewModels child namespace.
- View model names correspond with view names and end with “ViewModel”.

The blog also provide how to override Prism’s default conventions you can reference. [Brian's blog](http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/) also describe the similar things about the convention and how to change it.

Comment: I guess I have all the conventions followed, expect the 3rd one, View names end with “Page”. Like I mentioned in my question, I am trying to reuse most of the classic application code in the UWP version and since wpf prism does not include any constraints related to view ending with "Page", I hit a block. Is there a way I can manually wire views and viewmodels ?

Comment: @sudarsanyes I think yes. Could you please try the " Change those Nasty Conventions" section of Brian's blog?

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to rename the HighlightsView.xaml to be HighlightsViewPage.xaml

Comment: Yes, I realized it and have explained in my question... but what is the convention here?